# Firebase Cloud Messaging: strange message delivery

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I defined firebase service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public void onMessageReceived(com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        mgr.showNotification("X:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), "X:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {}
     @Override
    public void onMessageSent(java.lang.String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onSendError(java.lang.String s, java.lang.Exception e) {}
}
```

And android manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".integration.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

There are two very strange behaviours with the FCM I noticed:

1. Sometimes onMessageReceived() is called and sometimes not. It depends on whether my app is running or not. Anyway the notification is still displayed (that's why I added "X:")
2. Sometimes there is no notification and no onMessageReceived is called at all, but I can see in "FCM diagnostics" in developer console that message was acknowledged:

> ```
> Current Status    Acknowledged
> Collapse Key  <key>
> TTL   2,419,200
> TIME  CURRENT STATUS
> 20 Jun 17:35
> Device connected
> 20 Jun 21:23
> Accepted
> 20 Jun 21:23
> Delivered
> 20 Jun 21:28
> Acknowledged
> ```

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: How are you determining whether or not onMessageReceived is called? What does mgr.showNotification do?

Comment: @Marcin Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 3):

`onMessageReceived(...)` method will **not** get called **if** the app is in **background or killed** when the message is sent through Firebase Console.

BUT If you send the message via API, it works fine. Message is delivered in `onMessageReceived(...)` method whether app is in background, foreground or killed.

There are two types of messages in FCM:

- **notification**: work when your app is in foreground
- **data payload**: work even if your app is in background

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive

**Update:**

In case you don't know how to send a message using API, you can use a tool called [AdvancedREST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), its a chrome extension or similar, and send a message with the following parameters. Reference link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream

### Sending downstream messages from the server

To address or "target" a downstream message, the app server sets to with the receiving client app's registration token. You can send notification messages with predefined fields, or custom data messages; see Notifications and data in the message payload for details on payload support. Examples in this page show how to send data messages in HTTP and XMPP protocols.

### HTTP POST Request

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

You can get the server key (AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA), from firebase console: **Your project -> settings -> Project settings -> Cloud messaging -> Server Key**

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm sending messages using API. I tried data messages and mixed messages (containing both notification and data). Still onMessageReceived(...) is not always called when my app is not running :(.

Comment: @Marcin - On what Android version you are getting this issue? Are you testing it on a real device or emulator?

Comment: Real device, Samsung S5, And5.0

Comment: Can you post your API HTTP POST Request similar to given in my answer?

Comment: {"to":"d1wX...JJsG","data":{"title":"Welcome","body":"Welcome again. (2016-06-21 10:29:05)","url":"http://example.com","messageid":"215"}}

Comment: Hi, Are you successful in sending messages using API? If so please let us know how to overcome this challenge. And I don't know how to send a message using API, Please explain it if possible. Many Thanks

Comment: @RBhagwat Download a chrome extension called Advanced REST Client and put the HTTP POST Request data into the fields. Here is the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: @Hisham Muneer Thank you so much. I could achieve it:)

Comment: @Marcin did you fix this in the end?